# Split String by Two Characters Ignore Whitespace Before, In Between or After any of the Characters

Tags: c#, .net

I have an input string for example

```
var input = "'Test string','abc'";
```

I want to split it by exactly two characters that is ', ignoring white spaces before, in between or after the delimiters. For example based on the input I'm expecting the following output.

```
index0='Test string'
index1='abc'
```

I want to retain that output even if my input looks like any of these.

```
var input = "'Test string','abc'";
var input = "'Test string ','abc'";
var input = "'Test string' ,'abc'";
var input = "'Test string', 'abc'";
var input = "'Test string   '   ,   'abc'";
```

As long as there are two characters ', (single quote and comma) regardless that they have spaces before, in between or after, I want to split a string based on those two char delimiters. Splitting should only by two chars. If an input has only ' or , retain the input as is. Only split the input by ', not by any of the two chars. Please help. Here's my code.

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var input = "'Test string','abc'";
        var results = Regex.Split(input, @"[ ',]+");
        foreach (var item in results)
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
```

Comment: Can `'` or `,` occur in the quoted substrings?  Does "If an input has only ' or , retain the input as is." mean that if an input string contains `'` or `,` but not both it should be returned as-is?

Comment: Have you considered using a dedicated CSV parsing library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or regex with this pattern for optional white space `(?<=')\s*,\s*`

**Example**

```
var inputs = new []{ "'Test string','abc'", 
                     "'Test string ','abc'", 
                     "'Test string' ,'abc'", 
                     "'Test string', 'abc'", 
                     "'Test string   '   ,   'abc'", 
                     "Test string','abc','John's test'" };

foreach (var input in inputs)
{
   var results = Regex.Split(input, @"(?<=')\s*,\s*");
   foreach (var result in results)
      Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

**Output**

```
'Test string'
'abc'
'Test string '
'abc'
'Test string'
'abc'
'Test string'
'abc'
'Test string   '
'abc'
Test string'
'abc'
'John's test'
```

**Visualized**

[image]

[**Full Demo here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Widget/YM1oNo)

Comment: I've tested this solution and this is indeed what I'm looking for. Great job! Thanks for helping. It helped me save so many hours.

Comment: Regex ... urghh ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
string input = "'   Test string  ','abc'";
        string[] listInput = input.Split(',');
        foreach (string li in listInput){
          String output = li.TrimStart('\'').TrimEnd('\'').Trim();
            output = "'"+output+"'";
          Console.WriteLine(output);
        }
```

Comment: That works for that particular input, but with the last sample string in the question (`"'Test string   '   ,   'abc'"`) it won't remove the trailing spaces within `'Test string   '`.  Also, if it's possible for the quoted values to contain `,` (which is not clear from the question) this would then split the text between the quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Split by comma and trim single quote and spaces afterwards

```
var input = "'Test string   '   ,   'abc', 'John's test'";

var output = input.Split(',').Select(p => p.Trim().Trim('\'').Trim());

// Test string, abc, John's test.
```

Answer (score 0):

If the input is predictable and never contains an escaped quotation mark, you can do this:

```
input.Split('\'').Where((x, i) => i % 2 == 1).Select(p => p.Trim());
```

See it in use here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/AqookJ

---

```
input.Split('\'')
```

Splits the input by `'`

```
.Where((x, i) => i % 2 == 1)
```

Selects every second item of the split, which is everything inside of quotes in this context. For efficiency this can be changed to `(x, i) => (i & 1) == 1`

```
.Select(p => p.Trim())
```

Will remove whitespace from the beginning and end of every item in the collection.

---

**If however there are quotation marks inside of the target strings** you can use this following method:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> Split(string inpt)
{
    IEnumerable<string> res = Regex.Split(inpt, @"('\s*,\s*'|^\s*'|'\s*$)").Where((x, i) => i % 2 == 0).Select(p => p.Trim()).Skip(1);
    return res.Take(res.Count() - 1);
}
```

This will split the input by `'\s*,\s*'`, and also by `^\s*'` and `'\s*$`.

It will then discard the first and last items of the collection, which will be the first and last quotation marks.

See it in action here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/sQ6Y2x

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However my concern is that there might be input like this. var input = "'Test string','abc','John's test'"; splitting by single quote will split "'John's test'" into two. It should be only 1.

Comment: Is the quote in `John's` unescaped while inside of the other quotation marks?

Comment: @JobertEnamno Try this https://dotnetfiddle.net/sQ6Y2x. This method only works if the contents are always delimited by `','` (regardless of spaces between the characters)

Answer (score 0):

You can create method like below to get desired value. Call this method for each data.

```
private string GetValues(string input)
{
    StringBuilder newValue = new StringBuilder();
    string[] parts = input.Split(',');
    int counter = 0;
    foreach (string str in parts)
    {
        newValue.AppendLine("index" + counter++ + ":" + "'" + str.Trim().Trim('\'').Trim() + "'");

    }
    return newValue.ToString();
}
```

Input:

```
"'Test string','abc'";
"'Test string ','abc'";
"'Test string' ,'abc'";
"'Test string', 'abc'";
"'Test string   '   ,   'abc'";
"Test string','abc','John's test'";
```

Output is as below:

```
index0:'Test string'
index1:'abc'

index0:'Test string'
index1:'abc'

index0:'Test string'
index1:'abc'

index0:'Test string'
index1:'abc'

index0:'Test string'
index1:'abc'

index0:'Test string'
index1:'abc'
index2:'John's test'
```